# Is there a way to join two queries in SQL each with an order by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two queries that return data from two tables:

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    AE.id, AE.name, COUNT(R.id) 'number of reserves'
FROM 
    AIRPORT AE
INNER JOIN 
    FLY V ON V.id_destiny = AE.id
INNER JOIN 
    RESERVE R ON R.id_fly = V.id
GROUP BY 
    AE.id, AE.name
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(R.id) DESC;
```

Example of returned data:

| id | name | number of reserves |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | name1 | 27 |
| 4 | name2 | 18 |
| 14 | name3 | 14 |

and

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    AE.id, AE.name, COUNT(R.id) 'number of reserves'
FROM 
    AEROPUERTO AE
LEFT JOIN 
    FLY V ON V.id_destiny = AE.id
LEFT JOIN 
    RESERVE R ON R.id_fly = V.id
GROUP BY 
    AE.id, AE.name
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(R.id) ASC;
```

Example of data returned from this second query:

| id | name | number of reserves |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | name4 | 0 |
| 11 | name5 | 0 |
| 12 | name6 | 0 |

I need to combine these into a single output with the first query first (in the same order) and the second query next with the same order like this:

| id | name | number of reserves |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | name1 | 27 |
| 4 | name2 | 18 |
| 14 | name3 | 14 |
| 7 | name4 | 0 |
| 11 | name5 | 0 |
| 12 | name6 | 0 |

Is there a way to do it?

Edit: I have already tried the `union all` option, but I can't use the `group by` in each query so the table that is returned is different from what I need

```
(SELECT TOP 3 AE.id, AE.name, COUNT(R.id) 'number of reserves'
FROM AIRPORT AE
    INNER JOIN FLY V
ON V.id_destiny = AE.id
    INNER JOIN RESERVE R
ON R.id_fly = V.id
GROUP BY AE.id, AE.name)
UNION ALL
(SELECT TOP 3 AE.id, AE.name, COUNT(R.id) 'number of reserves'
FROM AEROPUERTO AE
    LEFT JOIN FLY V
ON V.id_destiny= AE.id
    LEFT JOIN RESERVE R
ON R.id_fly = V.id
GROUP BY AE.id, AE.name)
ORDER BY COUNT(R.id) ASC;
```

Comment: use [`UNION ALL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: You'll need to: 1) enclose each query in parenthesis, 2) use `UNION ALL` to consolidate them into one, 3) add `ORDER BY` to specify the order of the unioned result set.

Comment: already tried it, but it didn´t work because it sends an error if the group by is there.

Comment: `union all` with artificial column identifying the source, and then order by that column and calculated counts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enclosed each query in parenthesis, it is acting like a derived table. You will need a `SELECT` clause to select from the derived table.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    -- Your first query here
) AS Q1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM
(
    -- Your second query here
) AS Q2
```

You may also use `CTE` to do it

```
WITH 
Q1 AS
(
    -- Your first query here
),
Q2 AS
(
    -- Your second query here
)
SELECT *
FROM   Q1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROm   Q2
```

---

EDIT : if you also wanted the final result in the same order in both query, add another column for final query `ORDER BY`

```
WITH 
Q1 AS
(
    SELECT TOP 3 
           AE.id, AE.name, COUNT(R.id) 'number of reserves',
           Q  = 1,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(R.id) DESC)
    FROM 
           AIRPORT AE
    INNER JOIN 
           FLY V ON V.id_destiny = AE.id
    INNER JOIN 
           RESERVE R ON R.id_fly = V.id
    GROUP BY 
           AE.id, AE.name
    ORDER BY 
           COUNT(R.id) DESC
),
Q2 AS
(
    SELECT TOP 3 
           AE.id, AE.name, COUNT(R.id) 'number of reserves',
           Q  = 2,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(R.id) DESC)
    FROM 
           AEROPUERTO AE
    LEFT JOIN 
           FLY V ON V.id_destiny = AE.id
    LEFT JOIN 
           RESERVE R ON R.id_fly = V.id
    GROUP BY 
           AE.id, AE.name
    ORDER BY 
           COUNT(R.id) ASC
)
SELECT *
FROM   Q1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   Q2
ORDER BY Q, RN
```

Comment: That doesn't explain how to _explicitly_ order the results as specified by the OP. There is no guarantee that `union all` will produce the desired results.

Comment: I thought OP only wanted specifically the `ORDER BY` within each query. Anyway I have edited the answer and update with another query.

Answer (score 0):

I break the query and made two temp tables. You can do this in CTE (Commn Table expression) as well.

```
 SELECT TOP 3 AE.id, AE.name, COUNT(R.id) 'number of reserves'
 INTO #Temp_1
 FROM AIRPORT AE
    INNER JOIN FLY V
       ON V.id_destiny = AE.id
    INNER JOIN RESERVE R
      ON R.id_fly = V.id
  GROUP BY AE.id, AE.name


 SELECT TOP 3 AE.id, AE.name, COUNT(R.id) 'number of reserves'
 into #Temp_2
 FROM AEROPUERTO AE
    LEFT JOIN FLY V
      ON V.id_destiny= AE.id
    LEFT JOIN RESERVE R
      ON R.id_fly = V.id
  GROUP BY AE.id, AE.nam

  SELECT *
  FROM #Temp_1
  UNION ALL
 SELECT * 
  FROM #Temp_2

 drop table #Temp_1
  drop table #Temp_2
```